# Accessing images from a separate directory

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a solution in VS2010 with an image directory in   `<SolutionName/Styles/CustomerImages/SampleImage.jpg>`. 
I then have a separate folder holding a page in the following directory    `<SolutionName/Pages/AdministrativePages/Admin.aspx">`.
When accessing images directly in the solution i.e. "SolutionName/samplepage.aspx" it works just fine but when I try to access them from "Admin.aspx" i.e.     "SolutionName/Pages/AdministrativePages/Admin.aspx"
code behind file it doesn't work.
Code which works from samplepage.aspx is:

```
src = 'Styles/Customer Images/<%# Eval("Picture")>
```

Code which doesn't work from Admin.aspx is:

```
image src = '~/Styles/Customer Images/<%# Eval("Picture") %>'
```

I was of the impression it the "~" character goes to the root directory when used but that doesn't work.
I would appreciate it if anyone could show me the proper way of referencing files in the src attribute across different directories.

Comment: Can you please include the rendered HTML of those images.

Answer (score 0):

Use a server side ASP.NET image control to resolve this.

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='~/Styles/Customer Images/<%# Eval("Picture") %>'/>
```

Comment: I've updated the code using the asp image control with no change. I dont know if this will be of any help but with the other fields bound to the datasource like so ~/Styles/Customer Images/<%# Eval("Name") %> visual studio highlights the field in red, in this case that would be Name but in the case of picture it doesnt do that. Also it retrieves the name of the image just fine, it just cant reference it properly for display. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please check how the image src is rendered in HTML?

Comment: <img id="MainContent_FormView_Customers_CustomerImage" src="../../Styles/Customer%20Images/%3C%25#%20Eval(%22Picture%22)%20%25%3E%3E" style="height:220px;width:180px;" />

Comment: Your databinding is not working properly. Where is the image placed, inside repeater, gridview? Post more code for us to look.

Comment: <asp:FormView ID="FormView_Customers" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="EDS_Customers" BorderWidth = "1px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table border = "0" style = "width: 500px">
            <tr style = "background-color: #CCCCCC">
                <td style = "text-align: center">
                    <b>
                        Username: 
    
                <td style = "background-color: #274F7D">
                    <asp:Image ID="CustomerImage" runat="server" width = "180" height = "220" ImageUrl = '~/Styles/Customer Images/<%# Eval("Picture") %>>' />            </tr>